# wpf stringformat d

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

why is this displaying date and time (rather than just date)?

```
<ListView Name="AttachmentsLB" Width="160" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PicuAttachments}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Start" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate}" Width="80">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., StringFormat=d}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Finish" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FinishDate}" Width="80">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., StringFormat=d}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I have also tried StringFormat = {}{0:d} and StringFormat = \{0:d\} with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem of StringFormat on the wrong Binding

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Start" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat=d}" Width="75">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this? Change the StringFormat in your binding :

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=startDate, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'}"
```